# Force a ASP.NET MVC 3 action parameter to use value from the URL, not object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Consider a model class

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /* some other properties */
}
```

And a controller

```
public class MyController
{
    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult Update(string id, MyModel model)
    {
        /* process */
    }
}
```

The routing is registered as follows:

```
protected override void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute("MyController", 
                    "api/my/{id}",
                     new { action = "Update", controller = "My"},
                     new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new[] { "PUT" }) });

}
```

When using a REST client and sending MyModel serialized as a JSON or XML request to this controller, a null "Id" property of "MyModel", overrides the "id" parameter of the action method, even if you post it to http://api.example.com/api/my/10.

How does one force ASP.NET MVC 3 to populate the "id" property from the URL (in this case "10") and ignore the "Id" property of the "MyModel"?

Note that I'm not using ASP.NET Web API.

Answer (score 2):

Try using attribute **[FromUri]**. It's in "System.Web.Http". This attribute on action param id indicates it should be bonded using the url request.

```
using System.Web.Http;//at the top
public class MyController
{
    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult Update([FromUri]string id, MyModel model)
    {
       /* process */
    }
}
```

For MVC3 try to include web-api package(from nuget or manually) to use [FromUri] attribute. IF that is not possible then the only way I can think of getting it is from `this.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["id"]`

Instead of having id as a action method paramter declare it in action body. May have to change the url query api/my?id=1212. First try using api/my/{id} format.

```
var id = this.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["id"];
```

Comment: The `FromUriAttribute` is used by the MVC4 Web Api, and the OP stated that he is not using the web api.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for bringing this up. If webapi package is not included then the only way I can think of getting it is from `this.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["id"]`

Comment: Also not sure if the url should change to `api/my?id=` format to work with HttpContext.Request.QueryString way which may not be acceptable to OP.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a solution to this in ASP.NET MVC 3. I renamed the parameter from "id" to "resourceId" and left my model intact.